# Encountered "class" at line

Tags: python, django

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True,unique=True) 
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True) 
def __unicode__(self): 
    return self.title 
def get_absolute_url(self): 
    return (reverse('tags',[str(self.slug)]) 

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return (reverse('posts',[str(self.slug)])
```

**this is my model and ive got an idiotic error at the line of class:**

> Encountered "class" at line 16, column 1. Was expecting one of:
>   "(" ...     ")" ...     "[" ...     "," ...     "." ...     "+" ...
>   "-"   ...     "*" ...     "/" ...     "//" ...     "<<" ...     ">>"
>   ...     "%" ...     "^" ...     "|" ...     "&" ...     ">" ...
>   "<" ...     "==" ...     "<=" ...     ">="   ...     "<>" ...     "!="
>   ...     "or" ...     "and" ...     "not" ...     "is" ...     "in" ...
>   "if" ...     "for" ...     "," ...

what does that mean?

Comment: the `return` statement of `get_absolute_url` is missing a closing paren. Or on second thought, the opening paren in front of `reverse` is completely unneccessary and should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't close out one of your statements the line before. Look for unclosed parenthesis, quotations, or really any of the symbols listed in the error message that isn't correct. In fact, with your latest, code, I spotted:

```
return (reverse('tags',[str(self.slug)])
```

You are missing one parenthesis. Try this:

```
return (reverse('tags',[str(self.slug)]))
```

Comment: Looking at the expected tokens I would guess there's an unclosed `(` parenthesis in an expression.

Comment: Found it. It's amazing what including the code around it'll do.